# Как преобразовать результат функции datetime.timedelta в обычное число?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

Есть код, переводящий секунды в часы с использованием функции datetime.timedelta. Мне необходимо преобразовать вывод этой функции в обычное натуральное число(пр. : из 1:00:00 в 1)

```
import datetime
s = int(input())
print(datetime.timedelta(seconds=s))
# output(s = 3600): 1:00:00
```

Comment: почему 1? а во что должно перевестись 2:12:35?

Answer (score 2):

С помощью метода `total_seconds()` из дельты получить общее количество секунд,  поделить на 3600, привести к целому числу:

```
td = datetime.timedelta(seconds=s)
print(int(td.total_seconds() / 3600))
```